# How to load vertical plane between selected two SCNVector3 points?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit, arkit

I have selected two SCNVector3 points and load SCNBox same width and height of distance between two SCNVector3 points and fixe length. But Do not load proper between two points. How to load vertical plane properly between selected two SCNVector3 points.

Note : Material is not display proper size. material is starched and big.

```
let pos1 = SCNVector3(x: 0.26943, y: -0.022023335, z: 0.22480452)
let pos2 = SCNVector3(x: 0.3568532, y: -0.02038227, z: 0.30196056)

//Find distance between two points
let d = self.distanceBetweenPoints(A: pos1, B: pos2)
func distanceBetweenPoints(A: SCNVector3, B: SCNVector3) -> CGFloat {
    let l = sqrt(
        (A.x - B.x) * (A.x - B.x)
            +   (A.y - B.y) * (A.y - B.y)
            +   (A.z - B.z) * (A.z - B.z)
    )
    return CGFloat(l)
}

// width = distance between two points
//position = mid points of two points

func addwall(width:CGFloat, position : SCNVector3){

    let box = SCNBox(width: width, height: width, length: 0.001, chamferRadius: 0)

    let width = width
    let height = 2.3

    let material = SCNMaterial()
    //material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
    material.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "Titles.jpg")
    material.isDoubleSided = true

    material.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4MakeScale(1, -1, 1)
    material.diffuse.wrapS = .repeat
    material.diffuse.wrapT = .repeat
    box.materials = [material]

    var p = position
    let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: box)
    let (minVec, maxVec) = boxNode.boundingBox
    let unScaledHeight = maxVec.y - minVec.y
    let unScaledWidth = maxVec.x - minVec.x
    let unScaleddep = maxVec.z - minVec.z
    p.y = (p.y) + (unScaledHeight/2)
    boxNode.position = p

    boxNode.name = "wall"
    self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

I have used `SCNPlane` not `SCNBox` it would be easy as it has no depth

In `wallMaterial()`  you can simply create double sided `SCNMatirial`  object

In your case you need to rotate it so both edges matched with from and two point what `node.eulerAngles` does may be this only line solves your problem and may be not

```
func node(from:SCNVector3,
                to:SCNVector3,height:Float) -> SCNNode {
    let distance = MathHelper().getMeasurementBetween(vector1: from, and: to)

    let wall = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(distance),
                        height: CGFloat(height))
    wall.firstMaterial = wallMaterial()
    let node = SCNNode(geometry: wall)

    node.renderingOrder = -10



    let normalizedTO = to.normalized()
    let normalizedFrom = from.normalized()
    let angleBetweenTwoVectors = normalizedTO.cross(normalizedFrom)

    var from = from
    var to = to



    node.position = SCNVector3(from.x + (to.x - from.x) * 0.5,
                               from.y + height * 0.5,
                               from.z + (to.z - from.z) * 0.5)

    // orientation of the wall is fairly simple. we only need to orient it around the y axis,
    // and the angle is calculated with 2d math.. now this calculation does not factor in the position of the
    // camera, and so if you move the cursor right relative to the starting position the
    // wall will be oriented away from the camera (in this app the wall material is set as double sided so you will not notice)
    // - obviously if you want to render something on the walls, this issue will need to be resolved.


    node.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(0, -atan2(to.x - node.position.x, from.z - node.position.z) - Float.pi * 0.5, 0)


    return node
}
```

Comment: It's working! Thank you very much, But material is not apply properly. material is stretch.

Comment: You need to apply correct content transform to matirial